# undefined when combine combineLatest and switchMap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators, switchmap, combinelatest

I'm trying to combine two Observables to have few values for the call to service method that accepts two values. But here I have few errors

- Argument of type '([filter, sort]: [string, string]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [string, string], index: number) => ObservableInput'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
- in console -

  You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
  at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
  at innerSubscribe (innerSubscribe.js:71)
  at SwitchMapSubscriber._innerSub (switchMap.js:44)
  at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.js:34)
  at SwitchMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
  at CombineLatestSubscriber.notifyNext (combineLatest.js:73)
  at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
  at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
  at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:14)
  at BehaviorSubject._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)

1. Defining Observables and Subjects.

   ```
    private openSortQuerySubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.formatSortQuery(this.multiSortMeta));
    public openSortQuery: Observable<string> = this.openSortQuerySubject.asObservable();

    private closedSortQuerySubject: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.formatSortQuery(this.multiSortMeta));
    public closedSortQuery = this.closedSortQuerySubject.asObservable();
   ```
2. Combine observables.

   ```
      const openQueries$ = combineLatest([this.openFilterQuery, this.openSortQuery]);
      const closedQueries$ = combineLatest([this.closedFilterQuery, this.closedSortQuery]);
   ```
3. Use merged values in service method.

```
openQueries$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([filter, sort]) => {
          this.alertService
            .listAlerts(filter, sort);
        }),
        tap(v => console.log(v))
      )
      .subscribe((openAlerts) => {
        this.openAlertsCount = openAlerts.length;
        this.openAlerts = this.parseAlerts(openAlerts);
      });

    closedQueries$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(([filter, sort]) => {
          this.alertService
            .listAlerts(filter, sort);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((closedAlerts) => {
        this.closedAlertsCount = closedAlerts.length;
        this.closedAlerts = this.parseAlerts(closedAlerts);
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return an observable (or something RxJS knows how to turn into an observable) within a `switchMap` callback.

Not this:

```js
switchMap(([filter, sort]) => {
  this.alertService.listAlerts(filter, sort);
})
```

But this (assuming `listAlerts` returns an observable, a promise or similar):

```js
switchMap(([filter, sort]) => {
  return this.alertService.listAlerts(filter, sort);
})
```